# make my program "see" 64bit drivers

Tags: visual-c++, odbc, driver

I have to make an odbc connection to my database.
Problem is that when I compile my program it just sees drivers listed on odb admin 32bit, but drivers (oracle ones...) are listed under odbc admin 64bit so it gives me an "unrecognized driver" error.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your program for 64 bit to get access to 64bit ODBC APIs.

Comment: Are these specific apis and I have to rewrite code?Or I just need to compile already existing code with a 64bit compiler?

Comment: You may have to rewrite if your code is not portable to 64 bit(e.g. having a structure assuming a long or pointer to be 32 bit) or hit a problem from someone else (e.g. SQLDataSources returns both 32 bit and 64 bit user DSNs)